# No me crea ninguna interfaz grafica al ejecutar el programa python en visual studio code

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 

window = Tk()
window.title("Juego de piedra papel o tijera ")
window.geometry('720x600')
window.state(newstate = "normal")
window.resizable(False,False)

window.mainloop()
```

al momento de ejecutarlo no me aparece ninguna ventana, estoy usando visual studio code - python . tkinter
pero cada vez que lo ejecuto nada aparece si alguien tiene alguna solucion y me la indica le agradeceria un millon

Comment: probé tu código y funciona bien

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo usas? ¿Estás usando un entorno virtual de python? ¿Te sale algún mensaje de error? ¿No aparece la ventana pero el programa sigue ejecutando, o el programa termina sin mostrar la ventana?

Comment: Windows 10 - visual studios code y ahi tengo el python con el tkinte, ejecuto el programa y no aparece nada osea es como que carga como que si se hubiera corrido pero no aparece la ventana y solo me funciona cuando selecciono todo y le doy a run

Comment: Reinicia Kernel de la consola de Visual Studio Code